# How to import my browser a cookies to selenium java project?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a question.

I'm trying skip authentication in my QA-test in a webpage, because it's invoke captcha check.
I can skip authentication if i use my browse, because it saved a cookie. I have some ideas for solve this issue. I'm planning import my cookie from current browser. Cookie stored in cookie.sqlite database. I don't know how to import this data from database to selenium
I'm using: firefox, ubuntu.

I couldn't find information that help me import browser cookies to selenium test project.

Please, help me)

Comment: Learn how to use `SqlLite` with `java` programming: (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)

Comment: Hi, Ryan Wilson. I know about it. I can't get information from sqlite file, but i don't know how to import it to a cookie my selenium java project file. For Example, i get some row of information, but i don't know how to import it to cookies form in selenium. Thanks)

Comment: I know  about `driver.namage().getCookies()`, but i don't understand is it cookie selenium engin or my browser `firefox`?

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you. (https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html). Basically if you store the entire cookie text inside your database, you should be able to retrieve this and create a cookie with it using `driver.manage().addCookie(cookieFile)`